# out of memory when programming on Android platform

Tags: android, out-of-memory

I am programming a image segmentation algorithm on Android 2.2 platform. When run the following line of code:

```
double[][] temp=new double[328][576];
```

there is a out of memory exception.

However, I use the ActivityMannager.getMemoryInfo() to check the available memory space on the system and I find there is still 44851200 bytes free space.

I am confused that why there is a out of memory exception with still free space on the system?

Comment: try using `weak reference` for short life  variables in your application

Comment: `ActivityMannager.getMemoryInfo()` tells you about free memory for the *device*, not just your process.

Answer (score 7):

Android has limitation of memory allocation for each process/app. You can't use entire available memory on phone for your app only. Depending on device there is limit for each process max memory use. This [link](http://blog.javia.org/how-to-work-around-androids-24-mb-memory-limit/) may help you.